# node.js - Expect to receive 2 bytes per response but received whole byte string

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

As titled, I'm trying to emulate the streaming operation so I built a server that reads a text file `data.txt` with `My name is Eric`, which is 17 bytes. For the server, I created a reader stream to read the file to memory with 2 bytes and piped to the client when requested. For the client, it should print the 2-byte string per chunk but it didn't. Instead, it printed the whole string. My system is MacOS. Here is my code:

server.js

```
const http = require('http'); 
const fs = require('fs'); 

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 
const stats = fs.statSync("data.txt"); 
const fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"]; 

const server = http.createServer((req, res)=> {
    const before = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed/1024; 
    const stream = fs.createReadStream('data.txt', {
        highWaterMark: process.env.NUM_CHUNK
    }); 
    stream.on('data', chunk => console.log(chunk)); 
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', fileSizeInBytes); 
    stream.pipe(res); 
    const after = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed/1024; 
    console.log(`Memory Usage: ${after - before} kb`); 
}); 

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server is up and running'); 
});
```

client.js

```
const Fs = require('fs'); 
const Axios = require('axios'); 
const ProgressBar = require('progress');
const Path = require('path'); 

const url = 'http://localhost:3000'; 

async function downloadImage(url) {
  console.log('Connecting …')
  const { data, headers } = await Axios({
    url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'stream', 
    highWaterMark: 2
  })
  const totalLength = headers['content-length']
  console.log(`Total Length: ${totalLength/1024} kb`); 

  console.log('Starting download')
  const progressBar = new ProgressBar('-> downloading [:bar] :percent :etas', {
      width: 40,
      complete: '=',
      incomplete: ' ',
      renderThrottle: 0,
      total: parseInt(totalLength)
    })

  const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(
    Path.resolve(__dirname, 'images', 'code.txt'), 
    { highWaterMark: 2 }
  )

  data.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`\n${chunk}`); 
    progressBar.tick(chunk.length); 
  })
  data.pipe(writer)
}

downloadImage(url);
```

data.txt

```
My name is Eric.
```

result

```
// server
server is up and running
Memory Usage: 30.171875 kb
<Buffer 4d 79>
<Buffer 20 6e>
<Buffer 61 6d>
<Buffer 65 20>
<Buffer 69 73>
<Buffer 20 45>
<Buffer 72 69>
<Buffer 63 2e>
<Buffer 20 0a>

// client
Connecting …
Total Length: 0.017578125 kb
Starting download

My
-> downloading [====                                    ] 11% 0.0s
 name is Eric. 

-> downloading [========================================] 100% 0.0s
```

The working directory has two folders, client and server. Each folder contains a `main.js` file as entry point. For the server, run it with `NUM_CHUNK=2 node server`; for the client, `node client`.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Oops, sorry for that. Tag removed.

Comment: I don’t think highWaterMark option works with Axios, data stream buffer is 16kb.